# Why does it look like IPC messages from one menu item in Electron reach my window, but not when sent from another menu iteam?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have a simple application that needs to run a background process to get some data.  I would like to show a loading indicator while the data is being retrieved and I am having trouble with getting that done.

I am using `ipcrenderer` to receive the message in the main window.  My code is below:

```
//// main.js

const electron = require('electron');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');

const {
  app,
  BrowserWindow,
  Menu,
  ipcMain
} = electron

// SET ENV
//process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';

let mainWindow;
let addWindow;
let workerWindow;

// Listen for app to be ready
app.on('ready', function () {
  // Create new window
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({});
  // Load the HTML file into the window
  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'mainWindow.html'),
    protocol: 'file',
    slashes: true
  }));

  // Quit app when closed
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    app.quit();
  })

  // Build menu from menu template
  const mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(mainMenuTemplate);
  // Insert menu
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainMenu);
});

// Handle create worker window
function createWorkerWindow() {
  mainWindow.webContents.send('status:showLoading'); // This does NOT work
  // Create new window
  workerWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
    title: 'workerWindow',
    show: process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production' ? false : true
  });
  // Load the HTML file into the window
  workerWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'worker.html'),
    protocol: 'file',
    slashes: true
  }));
  // Garbage collection
  workerWindow.on('close', function () {
    workerWindow = null;
  })
  mainWindow.webContents.send('status:hideLoading'); // This does NOT work
}

// Catch item:add-worker
ipcMain.on('item:add-worker', function(e, item){
  console.log(item);
  mainWindow.webContents.send('item:add-worker', item);
  workerWindow.close();
});


// Create menu template
const mainMenuTemplate = [{
  label: 'File',
  submenu: [
    {
      label: 'Add Item from Worker',
      click() {
        mainWindow.webContents.send('status:showLoading'); // This does NOT work
        createWorkerWindow();      
      }
    },
    {
      label: 'Clear Items',
      click(){
        mainWindow.webContents.send('item:clear'); // This works
      }
    },
    {
      label: 'Show Loading',
      click(){
        mainWindow.webContents.send('status:showLoading'); // This works
      }
    },
    {
      label: 'Hide Loading',
      click(){
        mainWindow.webContents.send('status:hideLoading') // This works
      }
    },
    {
      label: 'Quit',
      accelerator: process.platform == 'darwin' ? 'Command+Q' : 'Ctrl+Q',
      click() {
        app.quit();
      }
    }
  ]
}];
```

When I use the `Show Loading` and `Hide Loading` menu items, the main window receives the message and does what it needs to do.  However, when I click the `Add Item from Worker` menu item, the message appears to not reach the main window.

```html
<!-- mainWindow.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src file: https:">
  <title>Shopping List</title>
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="mainWindow.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a class="brand-logo center">Shopping List</a>
      <div id="loadingIndicator" class="progress">
        <div class="indeterminate"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <ul></ul>
  <script src="mainWindow.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```js
//// mainWindow.js

// Show Loading
ipcRenderer.on('status:showLoading', function(){
    document.getElementById('loadingIndicator').style.display = 'block';
}); 

// Hide Loading
ipcRenderer.on('status:hideLoading', function(){
    document.getElementById('loadingIndicator').style.display = 'none';
});
```

I tried to add the `mainWindow.webContents.send('status:showLoading');` line in side the `click()` function for the menu item and inside the `createWorkerWindow()` function.  Neither appear to work.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that loading a url in a browser window isn't synchronous so when it runs `createWorkerWindow` it will send the `status:showLoading` message then it'll create the worker window and send the `status:hideLoading` all in a split second. If you wanted to hide the loading window after the worker window has finished loading you can use:

```
workerWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', function () {
    mainWindow.webContents.send('status:hideLoading');
});
```

Although keep in mind this will run when any url is loaded not just the first one.

[`did-finish-load` docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#event-did-finish-load)

Comment: Hello, Mike! Thank you for much for the help! It's a little embarrassing that I didn't realize that myself!  Anyway, for my purposes I really needed the 'destroyed' event. I should have been more clear in my original post as I 'close' the window once the process of grabbing the required data finishes. Thanks again for the help!